# Why is Rosetta dimmed when an application is moved to the Applications folder?

Tags: snow-leopard, rosetta

I'm trying to get VueScan working with my CanoScan 8000F. The final step is to start VueScan using Rosetta. 
When Vuescan.app is placed on the Desktop, everything works as it should.
Copying the same app to the Applications folder dims the Rosetta option.
Here'a screenshot showing the info screens of the two apps (on the Desktop and in Applications) side-by-side:
[image]

What can be causing this behaviour? Why is the Rosetta checkbox greyed out?
I'm on a MacBook Pro 5,3 with Snow Leopard running from an external disk.

Comment: What is shown under "Sharing & Permissions" in both pictures?

Comment: I've added a new screenshot. The difference seems to be that the one has `admin` instead of `staff` in the user list. But as I understand from [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/20430/141595) the `admin` has the same, if not more, permissions than the `staff` group.

Comment: `staff`/`admin` both are groups with just "read only", which means that for this application there is no difference.